# Pods terminating in AWS EKS cluster because the pod limit is reached even with enought resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We have 4 t3.medium instances (technically 17 pods allowed), but at some point, a lot of services crash and can't be restarted because the pod limit is reached.

```
0/3 nodes are available: 1 Too many pods, 2 node(s) had taint {node.kubernetes.io/unreachable: }
```

The problem is, that we only have deployed 13 Services in total, with 1 replicasets. How is this possible?

Even the AWS management interface tells us, that there is free space for more pods.

Comment: The error message in your question indicates that you only have 3 nodes and 2 of the nodes are unreachable. Are you checking the right cluster on the console?

Comment: Do you have cluster autoscaler set? Also can you tell us what does this command return - k get nodes and k top nodes

Answer (score 0):

your error message says that 3 nodes, not 4, and obviously maybe your 13 services running on only one node cause 2 of them are unreachable.
so first make sure that 2 nodes are reachable
then you shall make sure of application resources

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).